# ¿se puede generar un QR y guardarlo como imagen con ZXing.Net.Mobile.Forms?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, programación-móvil, zxing

Ya logro generar el QR, pero necesito guardar el QR, para que el usuario lo pueda mandar o imprimir, mi problema es que no he logrado obtener el QR en un formato más amigable para el usuario, es decir puedo mostrarlo en pantalla, pero no puedo obtenerlo en formato de imagen o pdf. de antemano gracias.